# Python Script to Search String in all file contents and also in subfolder

Tags: python, string-search

```
import os
from fnmatch import fnmatch

root = 'Directory'


for path, subdirs, file in os.walk(root):
for files in file : 
with open(files) as f:
        contents = f.read()
    if 'Search_string' in contents:
print os.path.join(path, files)
```

It is giving me below error :

```
    for files in file :
      ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Please help.

Comment: The error is self explanatory. You should indent the lines inside the `for` loop.

Answer (score -1):

Python language totally depends on indentation.You didn't give any indentation in your code.So you should give indentation in your code.You should follow this link for indentation.

[Structuring with Indentation](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_blocks.php).

```
import os
from fnmatch import fnmatch

root = 'Directory'

for path, subdirs, file in os.walk(root):
    for files in file : 
        with open(files) as f:
            contents = f.read()
            if 'Search_string' in contents:
                print os.path.join(path, files)
```